# SonarQube: VisitException: Visit failed for Component, Caused by: PersistenceException: Error updating database: space quota exceeded for tablespace

Tags: java, oracle, sonarqube, code-analysis, tablespace

Recently I have started having an issue with SonarQube analyses - they go through successfully, but fail to get persisted to the database. Hence, the end result is: Analysis **Failed**. I have tried **increasing the tablespace quota**, but that does not work. If anyone knows how to resolve this issue, please help me out. (SonarQube Version 5.6.6)

Here are the logs.

```
2018.05.15 04:22:12 ERROR [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Failed to execute 
task kwqejfcdjkds
org.sonar.server.computation.component.VisitException: Visit failed for 
Component {key=something:src/dir/custom,type=DIRECTORY}  located 
someProj(type=PROJECT)
at org.sonar.server.computation.component.VisitException.rethrowOrWrap(VisitException.java:44) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visit(PathAwareCrawler.java:52) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visitChildren(PathAwareCrawler.java:87) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visitImpl(PathAwareCrawler.java:70) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visit(PathAwareCrawler.java:50) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.step.PersistComponentsStep.execute(PersistComponentsStep.java:77) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.step.ComputationStepExecutor.executeSteps(ComputationStepExecutor.java:64) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.step.ComputationStepExecutor.execute(ComputationStepExecutor.java:52) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.report.ReportTaskProcessor.process(ReportTaskProcessor.java:75) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.executeTask(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:81) [sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.call(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:56) [sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.call(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:35) [sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_60]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_60]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_60]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_60]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_60]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_60]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_60]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60]
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error updating database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01536: space 
quota exceeded for tablespace 'USER'

### The error may involve org.sonar.db.component.ComponentMapper.insert- 
Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01536: space quota exceeded for tablespace 'USER'

at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:26) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:154) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.insert(DefaultSqlSession.java:141) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:51) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:52) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy40.insert(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.sonar.db.component.ComponentDao.insert(ComponentDao.java:278) ~[sonar-db-5.6.6.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.step.PersistComponentsStep$PersistComponentStepsVisitor.persistComponent(PersistComponentsStep.java:171) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.step.PersistComponentsStep$PersistComponentStepsVisitor.persistAndPopulateCache(PersistComponentsStep.java:163) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.step.PersistComponentsStep$PersistComponentStepsVisitor.visitDirectory(PersistComponentsStep.java:135) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visitNode(PathAwareCrawler.java:102) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visitImpl(PathAwareCrawler.java:67) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visit(PathAwareCrawler.java:50) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01536: space quota exceeded for tablespace 'USER'

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:208) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1046) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1336) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3613) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3714) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1378) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:172) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:172) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.update(PreparedStatementHandler.java:44) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.update(RoutingStatementHandler.java:69) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.ReuseExecutor.doUpdate(ReuseExecutor.java:50) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.update(BaseExecutor.java:105) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.update(CachingExecutor.java:71) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:152) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
... 29 common frames omitted
2018.05.15 04:22:12 ERROR [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Executed task | project=someProj | type=REPORT | id=kwqejfcdjkds | submitter=meghna | time=41263ms
```

Comment: Please format exception texts in your question.

Comment: @soufrk Thanks for your suggestion. I am new to this forum.

Answer (score 1):

This error comes from Oracle, you may have increase the quota of the tablespace *Users* to a too low value or maybe you increase the wrong tablespace ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick answer. There is 95% unused space. The error still persists.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a dedicated tablespace for your project

```
CREATE TABLESPACE ts_sonar SIZE ...
```

allow your user unlimited quota on the tablespace

```
ALTER USER uuu QUOTA UNLIMITED ON ts_sonar;
ALTER USER uuu DEFAULT TABLESPACE ts_sonar;
```

and move all tables and indexes to the new tablespace

```
ALTER TABLE ttt MOVE new_tablespace_name;
```